# Python : defining function that returns summation of all permutations

Tags: python, python-itertools

I have a python function  `a(i,j,k,l)`. For `0<i<100`, `0<j<100`, `0<k<100`, `0<l<100`, i get a single value with this function.

eg. `a(1,4,5,3) = 5`.

Now what I want is a function `b(i,j,k,l)` that can give me the sum of `a(i,j,k,l)` for all the permutations of `i,j,k,l`.

eg `b(1,4,5,3) = a(1,4,5,3) + a(1,4,3,5) + a(1,5,4,3) + a(1,5,3,4) + .....`. (as it is a permutations, so there will be `4!=24` such terms).

I saw `itertools.permutations` but I do not know how to use it to get the indices. Any elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and then unpack the values, like this

```
sum(a(*perm) for perm in permutations((j, j, k, l)))
```

For example,

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> from random import randint
>>> def a(*args):
...    return args[randint(0, len(args) - 1)]
>>> sum(a(*perm) for perm in permutations((1, 2, 3, 4)))
57
```

We are passing a generator expression to `sum`, which means that all the computed `permutations` are not stored in memory.

Comment: But I am getting an error with this - `TypeError: 'HDUList' object is not callable`

Comment: @Panchi What is a `HDUList`? You didn't mention anything about that in the question.

Comment: i dunno what that is :( i was doing - `for i in range(0,100):
    for j in range(0,100):
        for k in range(0,100):
            for l in range(0,100):
                def ggg(i, j, k,l):
                    return sum(a(*perm) for perm in itertools.permutations((j, j, k, l)))`

Comment: @Panchi Can you please edit the question and include the actual code?

Comment: it is a long code with lots of stuff, this might be a problem with a line before.. i will just check and let you know

Comment: @Panchi Whatever you mentioned in the above comment will be enough I guess

Comment: Thanks :) this works! That was a problem on some other line.. One day, I hope i can rebus python problems at this speed. thanks a tonnes!